# Is my Nvidia GeForce GTX 745 a good choice to do cryptocurrency mining (especially ethereum)?

Tags: mining

I have a graphic card that is relatively great and I wondering if I could use it to win some extra money from cryptocurrency mining! 
The graphic card is Nvidia Geforce GTX745. I searched all over the internet and didn't find it in any of the lists featuring great data mining graphic cards.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take these kinds of requests to one of the numerous mining communities. But if you didn't see it listed among mining GPU's then that kind of speaks for itself.

Answer (score 1):

You will need at least 3gb of ram for eth mining. Also AMD cards have proven to be faster and more efficient. Try zcash with nvidia cards